# print full page in windows

Tags: printing, gimp

fist off, if there is an exchange place more suitable for the question, please address me.

I'm designing some labels in gimp.
I created a A4 300dpi document and created the artwork, arranged them to use all the page. To measure the labels I create a rectangle with the "rectangle selection tool" and there one can inspect the size in cm:
[image: gimp tools]

I printed straight from gimp and to my surprise, the printed labels where smaller than designed. I assumed somehow someone along the line added margins to my already A4 document..

I tried saving to PDF and then printing the PDF, very similar results.

I'd say the difference is around 5%

What would be the appropriated method for printing exactly at the size I created the document ignoring any margins ??

I'm using Windows 10, HP ENVY 5010 and Gimp 2.10

Comment: The document has likely been scaled down to fit in the printable area of the page (there is usually some unprintable margin at the bottom due to paper traction).

Comment: is there a way to tell it to print without changing the size (just let blank where the cartridge cannot reach)

Comment: Yes, make your image shorter (you can likely keep the width) so that it fits the print area. This said, accurate printing with Gimp seems to be difficult, it is often easier to either: 1) use the montage printing in the Windows Image viewer, or 2) use your text processing app (Word, LibreOffice) to compose your page using the images that you export from Gimp. Also, if you want to print directly, make sure that the print definition of the image (Image>Print size) matches the printer's set definition.

Comment: moving to ms word seams the most straight way... Will this affect the resolution?

Comment: Normally not...

Comment: acording to some website the printing resolution on the ENVY 5010 is "Up to 4800 x 1200 optimized dpi color" and the printing area "Maximum print area (metric)
215.9 x 355.6 mm". So creating a canvas of this exact size will help ??

Comment: Print area depends on paper size. If you can fit 355mm into 297mm then you have a space warp machine :) `215.9 x 355.6` is really US "Legal" size. 4800x1200 is the print head resolution and you need several print dots to make a color pixel. Actual resolution is more likely 300 or 600PPI.

Comment: you are a clever man .. hehehehe I think I will try cutting the individual labels and pasting them into word and print from word .. sounds easier and .. if copy pasting does not affect resolution .. we are good to go like this